# How to use setUserVisibleHint for fragment in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

In my application i want use `fragment` and i want show `Toast` message just when users **see** this `fragment` show message.
I write below codes but when show `fragment` not show me any `Toast`!
In **java** i haven't any issue and show `Toast`, but when use **kotlin** **not** show `Toast`!

**My codes:**

```
class TestFragment : Fragment() {

    private val title by lazy { arguments?.getString("title") ?: "" }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        testFragText.text = title
    }

    override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
        if (isVisibleToUser){Toast.makeText(context, "Show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
    }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Is the fragment being shown anyway?

Comment: @laalto, no dear friend. i use BottomNavBar for show this

Comment: So if the fragment is not being shown, the issue is more likely in the code that instantiates and adds this fragment.

Comment: @laalto, why show when use java and not any issue?